# App Engine Cloud Endpoints Unit Testing, Issues with Data Nucleus, Is it possible?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, unit-testing, datanucleus, google-cloud-endpoints

We've built a basic RESTful API using Google App Engine Cloud Endpoints, and we're looking to unit test some of the code we've written, just to check that inserts and updates do everything that we expect for example.

I've looked into to [Local Unit Testing documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting) that Google provide, and implemented everything it suggests but am still getting crashes when `EntityManager.close()` is being called. I've added the 4 .jar files and am using `LocalServiceTestHelper` in my test file.

I was hoping someone could shed some light on the problem, I'm under the assumption that all I need to do is change a value in the `persistance.xml` to allow DataNucleus to run within local unit tests, or maybe a .jar file i'm missing?

I hope someone can help, one of the many users of Google App Engine! I can provide code but all i'm really doing is `EntityManager.persist(Obj); ... EntityManager.close();`

The Console output related to the problem is:

> `Jan 17, 2014 12:08:04 PM org.datanucleus.transaction.Transaction rollback`
>
> `SEVERE: Operation rollback failed on resource: com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreXAResource@556afa8, error code UNKNOWN and transaction: [DataNucleus Transaction, ID=Xid=, enlisted resources=[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreXAResource@556afa8]]`

Pointing to a datanucleus problem. The stack trace

> `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Illegal argument
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:298)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.close(JPAEntityManager.java:197)
>       at com.multipie.snapture.HashtagEndpoint.insertHashtag(HashtagEndpoint.java:124)
>       at com.multipie.snapture.tests.HashtagTest.testInsertHashtag(HashtagTest.java:30)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
>       at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
>       at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
>       at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
>       at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
>       at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
>       at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
>       at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: transactions on multiple entity groups only allowed in High Replication applications
>       at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:39)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:76)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:94)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:71)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:32)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionImpl.getHandle(TransactionImpl.java:97)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionImpl.getId(TransactionImpl.java:190)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseDatastoreServiceImpl.localTxnToRemoteTxn(BaseDatastoreServiceImpl.java:130)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.doBatchPut(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:532)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.put(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:490)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.put(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:444)
>       at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.put(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:86)
>       at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.WrappedDatastoreService.put(WrappedDatastoreService.java:112)
>       at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.putEntitiesIntoDatastore(EntityUtils.java:766)
>       at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjectsInternal(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:314)
>       at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:218)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2381)
>       at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.flush(JDOStateManager.java:3778)
>       at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flushInternalWithOrdering(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3888)
>       at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flushInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3811)
>       at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.flush(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3751)
>       at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.preCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:4141)
>       at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.transactionPreCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:428)
>       at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.internalPreCommit(TransactionImpl.java:398)
>       at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:287)
>       at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.close(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1090)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.close(JPAEntityManager.java:193)
>       ... 21 more`

Comment: "transactions on multiple entity groups only allowed in High Replication applications", so the problem is with GAE's Datastore, not with "DataNucleus"

Comment: Did you managed to write test towards Cloud Endpoints? I haven't found any documentation whatsoever about writing automatic tests towards endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, came across a google code project which helped me out - [datanucleus-appengine-test](https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine-test/).

When setting up `LocalServiceTestHelper` you need to set some special parameters on the `LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig`. Code as follows:

```
        // Create High-Replication-Datastore simulation
        LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig config = new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig();
        config.setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(1); // Can't be <1 and still have
                                                                    // multi-XG txns
        config.setStoreDelayMs(0);
        helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(config);
        helper.setUp();
```

Comment: This answer has a 1% chance to fail. Of course you can set a new random seed and fix it temporarily, but there is no guarantee it will work in another developer's machine.

Answer (score 0):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21188202/87987), There is a 1% chance that a datastore operation will be eventually consistent and probably test will fail. If it is set to 0% the LocalService will throw an exception. There is a better solution.

The config allows you to set custom high replication policy. You can overcome the issue by setting a policy such that your writes will always apply.

```
static final class ConsistentHighRepPolicy implements HighRepJobPolicy {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldRollForwardExistingJob(Key key) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldApplyNewJob(Key key) {
        return true;
    }
}


Config config = new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig()
                       .setAlternateHighRepJobPolicyClass(ConsistentHighRepPolicy.class);
```